# Image upload in textarea with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've looked all over for how to do this but can't seem to find anything that doesn't use a full out text editor. I want a user to be able to upload an image (using paperclip or dragonfly) in between lines in a textarea form. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using `ckeditor` gem.